# Maybe with the multinomial theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

I'm looking for some idea to prove
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\substack{ \left( s_{0},\ldots ,s_{r-1}\right) \in \left\{ \mathbb{N}%
\cup \left\{ 0\right\} \right\} ^{r}, \\ \sum_{a=0}^{r-1}\left( a+1\right)
s_{a}=r}}\binom{s_{0}+s_{1}+\cdots +s_{r-1}}{s_{0},s_{1},\ldots ,s_{r-1}}%
\left( \frac{-1}{2!}\right) ^{s_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{3!}\right)
^{s_{2}}\times \cdots \times \left( \frac{\left( -1\right) ^{r-2}}{\left(
r-1\right) !}\right) ^{s_{r-2}}\left( \frac{\left( -1\right) ^{r-1}}{r!}%
\right) ^{s_{r-1}}=\frac{1}{r!}.
\end{equation*}

From $\sum_{a=0}^{r-1}\left( a+1\right) s_{a}=r$, we have $s_{r-1}\in
\left\{ 0,1\right\} $. So,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\substack{ \left( s_{0},\ldots ,s_{r-2}\right) \in \left\{ \mathbb{N}%
\cup \left\{ 0\right\} \right\} ^{r-1}, \\ \sum_{a=0}^{r-2}\left( a+1\right)
s_{a}=r}}\binom{s_{0}+s_{1}+\cdots +s_{r-2}}{s_{0},s_{1},\ldots ,s_{r-2}}%
\left( \frac{-1}{2!}\right) ^{s_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{3!}\right)
^{s_{2}}\times \cdots \times \left( \frac{\left( -1\right) ^{r-2}}{\left(
r-1\right) !}\right) ^{s_{r-2}}=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text{for odd }r \\
\frac{2}{r!} & \text{for even }r%
\end{array}%
\right. .
\end{equation*}

Comment: Try generating functions.

Comment: This is somewhat reminiscent of the Lagrange inversion formula: the compositional inverse of a (formal) power series $x+\sum_{k\ge2}a_kx^k$ is $\sum_{n\ge1}b_ny^n$ with $$b_n=\frac1{n!}\sum_{\sum_i(i-1)m_i=n-1}\bigl(\sum_iim_i\bigr)!\prod_i\frac{(-a_i)^{m_i}}{m_i!}$$ where the indices $i$ run over integers $i\ge2$ (so they correspond to your $a+2$), and $m_i\ge0$.

Comment: Though I should better refer you to Bell polynomials.